# Reverse PHP function

Tags: php, math

I have a function that returns a user's **level** based on the user's **experience**. How would I go to reverse this, so that I can input the **level** and get the **experience** needed for that level?

```
function getLevel($experience)
{
    return round ( sqrt( pow($experience, 1.4) - 1.5*$experience +1) /100 );
}

function getExperienceByLevel($level)
{
    return ???;
}
```

This is what I have done so far, using regular maths. Since I know the **$level**, I want the expression to be like `$experience = XXXX`.

```
$level      = sqrt( pow($experience, 1.4) - 1.5*$experience +1) /100;
$level*100  = sqrt( pow($experience, 1.4) - 1.5*$experience +1);

pow($level*100, 2) = pow($experience, 1.4) - 1.5*$experience + 1;
```

Comment: pass another parameter on the main function and based on the value call the other function inside the main function

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Also, I could do a loop that called getLevel() until I got the level. But that seems like a very ugly way to do it.

Comment: Or you just run that loop once and hardcode an array with the lvl => xp so you can do a simple lookup

Comment: @Gordon That is one way to do it. However, wouldn't be more neat to actually solve the math instead?

Comment: depends. intellectually it certainly would be better, but if you hardcode the array you get a O(1) lookup, so it might be faster in terms of performance than doing the math. though I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: I think the function is more or less linear (it has a very soft slope), so you can get a straight line and calculate the reverse function. If I did correctly, you can aproximate it, if the value of level is not very low, to the function $experience = (625/91)*(8*$level - 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to do a bit of algebra here. The formula for level is

```
lvl = floor( sqrt( expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr +1) / 100 + 0.5)
```

to work backwards consider

```
lvl = sqrt( expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr +1) / 100 + 0.5
```

then

```
lvl - 0.5 = sqrt( expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr +1) / 100
```

and

```
100 * lvl - 50 = sqrt( expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr + 1)
```

square

```
10000 * lvl^2 - 10000 * lvl + 2500 =  expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr + 1
10000 * lvl^2 - 10000 * lvl + 2499 =  expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr
```

now let the lefthand side by Q so we have

```
expr^1.4 - 1.5*expr = Q
```

this is actually a hard equation to solve algebraically. An approximate value can be found by ignoring the linear part to get the simpler equation

```
expr^1.4 = Q
```

giving

```
expr = pow(Q, 1/1.4)
```

This actually tells us that it is probably better to solve it numerically. And you might as well construct a lookup table. A simple method is

```
int[] exprForLevel
function generateExprsForLevel() {
    curLevel = 1
    expForLevel[1] = 0
    for(i=0; i< MaxPossibleExperience; ++i) {
        lvl = getLevel(i)
        if(lvl > curLevel) {
            curLevel = lvl
            expForLevel[curLevel] = i
        }
    }

function getExperienceByLevel(level) {   
    return expForLevel[level]
}
```

The above pseudocode is quite inefficient as it checks every possible experience value. Computers are pretty efficient these day so you might find its good upto the several million experience. You might find a routine involving binary subdivision should converge to the values quicker.